# Delete button does not work inside Trash

Tags: nautilus, delete, trash

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Delete button works fine from any folder and shifts the file to trash bin. Shift+delete also works from everywhere (including the trash). But the delete button doesn't do anything inside the trash bin.

Shouldn't the delete button delete the file from the trash bin when used inside it? Is it by behaviour that delete button has no functionality inside the trash bin or just a bug that I am experiencing?

Answer (score 0):

The Delete button as you said deletes a file and moves it into the trash, but one inside it has no use since you must then click Empty Trash or right-click and select Empty Trash to remove files from inside the Trash folder...  You can also right-click a file and Restore it back to it's original location...

Comment: Wouldn't it be more intuitive for the delete button to function as remove from trash, within the trash folder?